# Where is the JSON data stored ? (Android App development)

Tags: android, json, parsing

I want to parse data into the app through JSON. Where is this JSON file stored ? Do I store it on a server if I launch the app on play store ?

Will it be secure ?

Comment: Hi,
Why is it being down voted ? Can you please help if this question is fundamentally wrong ? It might help me learn. (I am new to it, it must be evident from the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends if your data is dynamic or not. If it is, you should generate it on the server using for example PHP and request it in your application ushering a HTTP request.

If your data will not change in the feature you could place a JSON file in the 'raw' folder under the 'res' folder or in the assets folder. However, I think that in most use cases where the data is text to be displayed the data could best be put into the strings.xml file